# Netbeans empty screen

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Im having a problem with netbeans gui I have made other gui(s) before but i have recent encountered a problem when i open a new window through a button which i normally do it only opens a empty gray screen. Keep mind the FIRST Form labelled main works but when i click on the button that should open the next window i only get a gray empty screen.

```
package wecare;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 *
 * @author dnnmc
 */
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Main
     */
    File Reg= new File("Users.txt");
    public Main() {
        initComponents();
    }

    void ReadFile()
    {

            try {
                FileReader fr= new FileReader(Reg+"Users.txt");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("File exist");


    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        SgnBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        Unametxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        PwordTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        LogBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setLayout(null);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 255));

        SgnBtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        SgnBtn.setText("Sign Up");
        SgnBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SgnBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Agency FB", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel4.setText("WeCare");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                        .addComponent(SgnBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(59, 59, 59)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 94, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(78, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(162, 162, 162)
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 170, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(SgnBtn)
                .addGap(110, 110, 110))
        );

        jPanel1.add(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setBounds(0, 0, 240, 530);

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("User Name");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Password");

        LogBtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        LogBtn.setText("Login");

        jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/wecare/rsz_1rsz_man.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("jLabel5");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(Unametxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 164, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(PwordTxt))))
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(88, 88, 88)
                        .addComponent(LogBtn))
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(59, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(Unametxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(PwordTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                .addComponent(LogBtn)
                .addContainerGap(115, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel1.add(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setBounds(240, 0, 260, 530);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 502, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 533, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void SgnBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        SignUp  sg= new SignUp (Reg);
        sg.setVisible(true);
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton LogBtn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField PwordTxt;
    private javax.swing.JButton SgnBtn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Unametxt;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

```
    package wecare;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author dnnmc
 */


public class SignUp extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  private File reg;
    /**
     * Creates new form SignUp
     */



    public SignUp() {
        initComponents();
    }

public SignUp(File Reg)
{
    reg=Reg;
}
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        UsnameTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        CPwrdTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        PwrdTxt1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        CrteBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        EmailTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 255));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Sign Up");

        jPanel4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Username");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Password");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Confirm Password");

        CrteBtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        CrteBtn.setText("Create");
        CrteBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CrteBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Email");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                        .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(PwrdTxt1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(UsnameTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                                .addComponent(CPwrdTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(EmailTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(149, 149, 149)
                        .addComponent(CrteBtn)))
                .addContainerGap(64, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(UsnameTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(PwrdTxt1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(CPwrdTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(EmailTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(CrteBtn)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(197, 197, 197)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                        .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(55, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(56, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void CrteBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        String pwd;
        String pwd1;

        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("User.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(UsnameTxt.getText());
            bw.newLine();
            pwd=PwrdTxt1.getText();
            pwd1=CPwrdTxt.getText();
            if (pwd.equals(pwd1))
            {
                bw.write(PwrdTxt1.getText());
            }
            else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Password dont Match");
            }
            fw.close();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }                                       

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SignUp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SignUp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SignUp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SignUp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SignUp().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField CPwrdTxt;
    private javax.swing.JButton CrteBtn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField EmailTxt;
    private javax.swing.JTextField PwrdTxt1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField UsnameTxt;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SignUp constructor that takes the File parameter, Reg (which should be re-named `reg` to comply with Java naming conventinons) never appears to call `initComponents()`, the method that creates the components that need to be added to the GUI before it is displayed. Without this being called, I would expect the window should remain empty. To fix: call this method in the class's constructor.

This can be done by calling `this()` within the second constructor in order to first call the no-args default constructor:

```
public SignUp(File reg) { // reg should not be capitalized
    this(); // first call the no-arg default constructor.
    this.reg = reg;
}
```

or you can solve this by calling the method directly:

```
public SignUp(File reg) {
    initComponents(); // put gui elements into the window
    this.reg = reg;
}
```

The first way to me seems cleaner in that if you decide to add more functionality to your class's constructor, you only have to do it once, avoiding running afoul of the "DRY" rule.

Comment: Omg thank you im new to this gui thing so i just dont bother with the code that is already there

Comment: @J.DoeKl: this really has little to do with being a GUI issue but rather is a bread and butter Java issue any time you have constructor overloads.